# Create String Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, matrix, malloc

I want to create an array of N positions. In every position, I want to store a 10 character string.
This is what I tried. In the example given, N = 15. But this number can change.

```
char *userArray[10] = malloc(sizeof(char[10])*15);
```

When compiling iget an error: invalid initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You want pointer to the array of 10 `char` elements, not pointer to `char`

```
char (*userArray)[10] = malloc(15 * sizeof(*userRrray));
```

Then you can use it as normal array:

Examples:

```
strcpy(userArray[3], "Hello");

print("%s\n", userArray[3]);
print("%c\n", userArray[3][4]);
```

To return this array you need to define function like this:

```
char (*allocate(size_t size))[10]
{
    char (*userArray)[10] = malloc(size * sizeof(*userArray));

    return userArray;
}
```

Comment: If I want to return this array, what should type should I write in the function header? "char* [10] funcion(){}"??

Answer (score 0):

> `char *userArray[10] = malloc(sizeof(char[10])*15);`

You have not cleared whether your variable `userArray` is stack or heap allocated and what's the dimension of the `userArray`?

Arrays in C can be of two types (based on where they are stored):

1. Stack Memory Arrays
2. Heap Memory Arrays

### Stack Memory Arrays

You can initiate a array which is going to be stored on stack memory like this:

```
int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

Now, to obtain array's length use this:

```
size_t length_arr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
```

### Heap Memory Arrays

You can initiate a array which is going to be stored on heap memory like this:

```
int *arr = (int *)calloc(10, sizeof(int));
```

Now, do not use `sizeof` to obtain `arr`'s length because `sizeof(arr)` will return the size of the pointer, which in my case is 8.
*So, you need to keep track of the length of array.*

Also, do not forget to `free()` the heap allocated resource after use.
For freeing heap allocated resources snippet will be:

```
free(arr);
```

NOTE: Must include `stdlib.h` header file before using functions like `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` or `free()`.

Comment: Please don't ask for acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

> char *userArray[10] = malloc(sizeof(char[10])*15);

**malloc**(3) returns a pointer, and `*userArray[10]` is not a pointer.  It's an array of 10 pointers.  You can't initialize an array — any array of anything — with a pointer.  An array can be initialized only with values.  The compiler, not you, decides the array's address.

The definition you want is

```
char userArray[15][10]
```

That's an array of 15 elements, with each element itself an array of 10 chars.  Another way to say the same thing:

```
typedef char elem_t[10];  
elem_t  userArray2[15];
```

A typedef like that is useful when the array elements represent something that occurs elsewhere in the program, so all such variables have the same type and size.

Now I will offer some controversial advice: don't use **malloc**(3) with constant arguments. If you know the value at compile time, you don't need malloc.  malloc is for *dynamic* memory, memory whose size is determined at runtime, by a value not known at compile time.

Someone will warn you that large arrays can't be allocated on the stack (technically, *automatic* storage in C).  That's true, but you have *static* storage available, either local to a function or at file scope.

There are a few rare cases that justify using statically sized dynamic memory.  While you're learning the language, you can assume they don't exist.  In 35 years of using C, I doubt I've seen a dozen examples.