# Why Segmentation Fault for this below code?

Tags: c

This following code gives Segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* str = "hello world";
    str[0] = 'H'; // it is throwing segmentation fault.
    
    printf("%s",str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to modify a string literal, which you can't do. One alternative is to make `str` be defined as `char str[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` pointers defined with an initialization value goes into a read-only segment. To modify them later in your code you need to make it to store on heap memory using `malloc()` or `calloc()` functions, or define them as arrays. [Must Read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70907458/17939455)

**Cannot be changed:**

```
char *ptr1 = "Hello, World!";
```

**Can be changed:**

```
char ptr2[] = "Hello, World!";
```

**Example for Heap-Memory:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char *str = calloc(14, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(str, "Hello, World!");
    
    printf("Before: %s\n", str);
    str[0] = 'Q';
    printf("After: %s\n", str);

    free(str); // heap-allocated memory must be freed
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Example of Array (stack allocated memory):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char str[14] = {}; // decayed to pointer, but `sizeof()` operator treats this as an array in C
    strcpy(str, "Hello, World!");
    
    printf("Before: %s\n", str);
    str[0] = 'Q';
    printf("After: %s\n", str);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```